# vee-validate dose not change language

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vee-validate

I am trying to change the error message in vee-validate and it doesn't work...

Some one knows how to fix that?

```js
import VeeValidate from "vee-validate";
import hebrew from "vee-validate/dist/locale/he";

Vue.use(VeeValidate, {
  locale: "he",
  dictionary: {
    he: { messages: hebrew }
  }
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I finally found the right way

```
import VeeValidate, { Validator } from "vee-validate";
import he from "vee-validate/dist/locale/he";

Validator.localize({ he: he });
Vue.use(VeeValidate, { locale: "he" });
```

Comment: and how to change the locale? this.Validator.localize(i18n.locale); it dosne not work